# How to set gojs code make one itemArray does not affect the other one

Tags: javascript, gojs

I`m the new guy.
I want to ask for help about the go.js。

My code is here [enter link description here](https://github.com/yourenA/goJs)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqwL8.gif)

just like the picure,when I modify the right box's param1 from 100 to 1000,the left box's param1 also be change.

When I remove the makeTwoWay funtion on line 100,although the box doesn't affect another one ,but I can't use the 'myDiagram.model.toJson' funtion to get the result that I modified.

I hope someone can tell me how to change the code to make the box doesn't affect the another one and I can get the result the I had modified.

Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Please avoid posting the code as a link, instead insert the relevant parts of the code directly in your question and try to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to set **Model.copiesArrays** and **Model.copiesArrayObjects** to true.  Read more about this at http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Model.html.